How to handle bias in 1-5 star ratings?
I was discussing with a friend my bad experience with a health insurance company, and as support for my impression, I pointed out to her that trustpilot gave it a very low score.
There were 70 reviews, distributed as: {1: 61, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 5} (as in number of stars: number of votes).
Her reply was: 'oh but there are only 70 reviews, so it does not count'.
My initial thought was that 70 was not such a small number; looking at the multinomial distribution, it would be quite unlikely to obtain such a negative outcome by random chance, if people were actually overall happy with this insurer.
On further reflection, it occurred to me that perhaps the problem was not with the number of reviews, but with the probable bias in the data collection process.
As this was not the result of a survey where truly random people were selected, but a case of spontaneous reporting, are the data really representative of the overall customer population?
E.g. is it possible that people who are happier with the insurer are less likely to leave a review, and vice versa, those who are less happy are more likely to report their discontent?
Supposing that it is so, is there any known method or approach to reduce this bias?
E.g. could one weight the reviews according to some probability distribution?
Some more information below, just to illustrate my further research and thought process.
I saw some posts about Bayesian estimations of averages, like this one, and indeed, the average rating on trustpilot from the above data is not what one would get by a simple arithmetic mean.
However, I am not sure that addresses the bias issue I am discussing here, as it seems more focused on comparing pairs of ratings that would have the same purely arithmetic average, but are based on different total numbers of reviews. In that sense of course I cannot but agree that a correction is necessary. But does it address the data collection part?
The mean score of the insurer example I am discussing (not taking into account the Bayesian correction or whatever other corrections that trustpilot does) is:
$$\frac {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n) \cdot n}} {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n)}} = \frac {61 \cdot 1+3 \cdot 2+ 0 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 5} {70} = \frac {48} {25} \approx 1.37$$
Very simplistic example of what I would guess a bias correction might look like: suppose we know that the probability that someone whose opinion of the insurer is 'n stars' writes a review is proportional to $\frac 1 n$.
Then the $PMF(n)$ would be $\frac 1 n \cdot \frac {60} {137}$.
Meaning that if $x(n)$ people voted $n$ stars, the actual population of people that had that rating in mind is proportionally larger by a factor $\frac 1 {PMF(n)}$. (BTW I am making this up as I go, so please do correct me if I am wrong: the goal of this post is to ask for advice on this matter).
If I am not mistaken, the corrected average according to this logic would be:
$$\frac {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n) \cdot n \cdot \frac 1 {PMF(n)}}} {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n) \cdot \frac 1 {PMF(n)}}} = \frac {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n) \cdot n^2}} {\sum_{n=1}^5 {votes(n) \cdot n }} = \frac {61 \cdot 1^2 + 3 \cdot 2^2 + 0 \cdot 3^2 + 1 \cdot 4^2 + 5 \cdot 5^2} {61 \cdot 1+3 \cdot 2+ 0 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 5} = \frac {103} {48} \approx 2.14$$
The way I am looking at this is: as the people who had higher satisfaction with the insurer were less likely to write a review and vote, this method gives more weight to their vote, to approach a bit better the average that one would get if it were possible to get votes from everyone in the population.
Does this make sense?
And as per above question, are there any such methods aimed at reducing the bias that may result from spontaneous reporting vs designed polling?

You can look at keywords like horvitz thompson estimator or IPW estimator for some ideas.

re: "is it possible that people who are happier with the insurer are less likely to leave a review, and vice versa, those who are less happy are more likely to report their discontent?", it might be informative to check reviews for other health insurance companies.

I can not help but be reminded of this cartoon https://www.reddit.com/r/mathmemes/comments/uoc3zq/interesting_survey/ The question btw  is indeed  valid; voluntary surveys can always be suspected of bias. But, in what direction is another matter.

@jginestet :D: D: D thank you, I needed a laugh today :)

The problem here is that although chances are you're right and there is a systematic bias, there are no data that allow you to say what the bias actually is. In order to know how the population of those who respond relates to the overall population, you'd need to have some information about how these populations differ, and such information would require data from those who don't respond, but you don't have data from those.
A comment mentioned the Horvitz-Thompson estimator and Inverse Probability Weighting, but these assume that you know the weights, i.e., you know for example how much more likely it is for somebody who doesn't state their rating that their true rating is 5 than for somebody who states their rating indeed. Essentially the same applies to your calculations.
In some situations (but chances are that yours is not one of them) there is some secondary information that could be used such as demographic information about the raters which you could compare with an overall population and then potentially correct for the fact that, say, young people give more positive ratings than older ones, and the former are overrepresented in the data. Also of course with big resources you could try to reach people who haven't rated and find out what they think in order to find something out about what bias you might have overall. All of these, however, may not be available in your situation, and so you can't know.
There may be some literature on surveys that makes general statements about what kind of bias to expect in such situations, backed up empirically from situations that may be different but still somewhat similar to yours, but I don't have the time to look for it.
Assuming that the bias is the same for all insurers, data can still be reliable for comparing insurers, and you can make relative statements. Unfortunately even the assumption of constant bias is somewhat questionable, but looks tolerable as long as there is no specific suspicion how different bias for different insurers could play out (quite certainly bias for insurers may differ from other kinds of companies). What may happen is for example that somebody runs a campaign against or in favour of a specific insurer using lots of fake accounts. trustpilot may try to detect such things but that may very well not work perfectly. Such things have the potential to bias ratings away from any level of usefulness.
Regarding the number of reviews I'd agree with you that 70 is a fairly solid number and bias is the much bigger issue.

Thank you, very useful answer! I was indeed not thinking of comparing different insurers, but just trying to get a more balanced view of this specific insurer's scoring, partly to understand if my friend had a point saying that this rather negative score 'did not count'. And indeed, in the absence of any solid information about how the reporting propensity is related to the number of stars, any speculation I can make is not going to improve anything. I suppose we can only take this sort of 'at face value', and indeed 70 is not a number to be scoffed at.

I would say that the best way of accounting for bias in this sort of rating is to not try to use these ratings as a measure of quality, but rather as an alert system to failures or successes.
I don't know of specific examples of this with insurance, but I do know that many hotels use the rating cards they leave in your room in this way. If you leave a very low rating, they look at what happened; similarly if you leave a very high rating.
For many of this sort of rating, the distributions tend to be U shaped. People don't fill these out unless they are very upset or very happy.
If you  want unbiased ratings, use a different data collection method.

"People don't fill these out unless they are very upset or very happy." I've said for years about RateMyProfessor as well, but my undergrads didn't realize why it made sense.

I think for your specific problem the easiest solution is to look at the reviews of other health insurers.
You assume there is some bias in the reporting, maybe people who had a 1 star experience will write a review with 50% probability whereas people who had a 5 star experience only write a review with 10% probability. You don't know what this bias is exactly and you don't need to know that but you make the assumption that this bias is the same for all health insurers.
If you now have the reviews of another health insurer and for that insurer the ratio of 1 star to 5 star reviews is roughly 3 to 1 (compared to the 12 to 1 in your example) you can confidently conclude that this other insurer provides better experiences on average.
If you want to know how much better the experience is you would still need to know the bias in writing reviews but maybe that is not needed to make your decision.

"you can confidently conclude that this other insurer provides better experiences on average". While I suggested in an earlier comment that it could be informative to look at data for other companies, I disagree with your statement. Without more information about the data collection process, we can't dismiss the possibility that there was a coordinated campaign against/for one of those companies, as mentioned in Christian Hennig's answer. So I wouldn't say we can be confident about such a conclusion, without taking into account the whole context.

@J-J-J Note that I made the assumption that bias is the same for all insurers. If you make the assumption you can conclude they are better. If this assumption doesn't hold, for example because there was a campaign against/for one insurer, then you can't draw this conclusion.

It is crucial to determine if this assumption is justified or not. I find this might be a point that could be missing in your answer, or perhaps that could be made more explicit.

@J-J-J I agree that the usefulness of this approach crucially depends on this assumption. But I think per definition you can't test whether that assumption holds from the data alone. We agree that there are differences in the underlying quality of the insurers, that is what we would like to measure. If you assume that the rating you see depends not only on the quality of the insurer but also on the specific insurer then just looking at the ratings does not allow you to disentangle the two effects. You would need some additional external data source for that.
